# List of Zylberman Schools in the US

Tags: yeshiva-school, united-states

Is there a list of schools/yeshivos that implement (at least partially) the [Zylberman method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilberman_Method) of teaching Judaic studies, especially in the northeast United States (e.g. by focusing on studying/memorizing most/all of Tanach between ~5 and ~10 years of age; studying/memorizing most/all of Mishnayos/Rambam/Halachic codes between ~10 and ~15 years of age; and only engaging in in-depth Talmudic analysis in adolescence [e.g. at ~15], as per [Avoth 5:21](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%90) and as advocated for by, e.g., the Maharal and Vilna Gaon)?

Comment: There are none in the U.S. that follow the full Zylberman method. The last one closed about a decade ago.

Comment: Don't forget the gra on that mishna that shmone esre lichupa is a last chance. Preferably it's 13.

Comment: There was one kinda zilberman yeshiva in Brooklyn that also employed Montessori. They ended up turning into a social ed school and are slowly closing down. The big question is where are the gedolim that this type of teaching claims to produce?

Comment: It seems the only one in the States might be in Lakewood: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%98%D7%AA_%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%9F (?)

Comment: There are gedolim from other schools too. The point is do they have any statistical advantage at being able to produce gedolim?

Comment: @user6591 who says the goal is to produce gedolim?  Maybe it's to promote a basic level of literacy for everyone.  There are way too many people who couldn't tell you a thing about Tzefanya even though they know Bava Kama almost by heart.

Comment: @Heshy who said that's not what I meant by gedolim?

Comment: @user6591 got it!  I thought you meant it in the colloquial sense.

Comment: Tzephania seems to be one of the few treiAsar not quoted in BavaKama. @Heshy

Comment: @Loewian The one in Lakewood closed down around a decade ago.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I wish I could say I did that on purpose

Comment: Consider adding even shleima 8.2 and kesubos 50a to your list of references (or even shabbos 63a).